# Randomly choosing a fixed number of list items?

Tags: html, list, random

I'm creating a memory game, where the user has to match a word on one card to its definition on another card.

Currently, I have everything in a list, and the word/defintion are linked together by the same class name.

```
<li class="match1"> 1 </li>
<li class="match2"> Two </li>
<li class="match1"> One </li>
<li class="match2"> 2 </li>
```

My question is, since I don't want to have the same words appear every time, how would I go about randomly selecting only a few different class names to appear on the page, out of many more.

For example, If I want to have the above code go up to 50, but only display 6 different words at a time?

I'm just using the "1" and "one" as an example,  I'll actually be using vocabulary and definitions if it matters at all.

Comment: You do realize you're going to need either Javascript or a serverside language like PHP or C# for this? With a serverside approach this is a trivial problem, with Javascript only slightly harder.

Comment: Yes I do.  I was just wondering what the most efficient way of doing this would be.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'd continue that class naming convention -

Put a `li { display: none; }` to pre-hide all the options, then:

```
//Set these as you wish
var totalOptions = 50, showOptions = 6, random;

//Loop this code as many times as the value of showOptions
for (var i = 0; i < showOptions; i++) {

    //Generate a random number between 1 and the value of totalOptions
    do {
        random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*totalOptions);
    }
    //Loop while the chosen value is something already shown
    while (document.getElementsByClassName('match' + random)[0].style.display == 'list-item');

    //Hide word && definition by class name
    document.getElementsByClassName('match' + random)[0].style.display = 'list-item';
    document.getElementsByClassName('match' + random)[1].style.display = 'list-item';

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkyHS/)